# python: Python script knows user that started this script last time?

Tags: python

Is it possible to store name of the user that started my script last?
I want to have something like this:

1. user1 launched script
2. user2 launched script

python myscr.py
Last started by: user1
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [getpass.getuser()](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser)

```
>>> import getpass

>>> getpass.getuser()
'me'
```

**EDIT :**

Well in general case to log each time the scripts runs and the user i will definitely use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) for that; something like this maybe:

```
import logging
import getpass

FORMAT = "DATE : %(asctime)-15s USER :  %(message)s FILE : %(filename)s"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format=FORMAT, 
                    filename='users.log', 
                    filemode='a')

logging.debug(getpass.getuser())
```

Ouput :

```
DATE : 2011-01-11 15:06:26,465 USER : me    FILE : zzz.py
```

Comment: how can I store getpass.getuser() result? 1. 'user1' ran script, script execution finished. 2. 'user2' runs script(from another session of course) and I want user2 to see that last user who used script was user1

Comment: @user553131 : Where you want to store them exactly in a database ...? so that i can give you more detail.

Comment: I don't what possible solutions are. Can you propose some?

Comment: @user553131 : it depend on what you want to do with this data, so it will be very helpful to tell us what you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store it. In a file, or in the windows registry if you are on windows, or in a database, or in a datastore if you are on some server, or you can store it *on* a server.

Maybe you can give some more information about your actual problem, and also tell us what you have tried, and why that failed?

Comment: Yes, your operating system version would be useful. Especially if its a single-user OS, then various concurrency problems neatly disappear.

Comment: @user553131: Then the correct answer most likely is "in a file".

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module. Use `getpass.getuser()`, and then just store that in a file for the next execution?

```
 f = open('lastuser')
 f.write(getpass.getuser())
 f.close()

 # Next time
 user = open('lastuser').read()
```

Comment: using files is not the best choice for me. In java swing I used properties which does not require external resources? Is there something similar to this in python?

Comment: Just dont forget to f.close() and hope and pray that two people don't run the thing at the same time. Also, every user will need *write* access to the file (and the folder it lives in). Is this meant to be a robust piece of mission-critical code or a quick hack?

Comment: Where do you think Java stores its properties? In magic pixie dust? Its an abstraction onto files. Similar things exist for Python, so you could use config.ini-style files in Python. Depends how complex and robust you want to make it.

Comment: @Spacedman - that hope that two people won't run at the same time will always be broken - usually when it matters most

Comment: Java Preferences: Where is the Preferences Data Really Stored? >>> On Solaris and Linux, the user node is normally stored in a hidden file in the user's home directory. When someone will be looking at the he will not find (read) what file exactly is used. So I need something similar in python.

Comment: @user553131: Oh, you want security by obscurity. I see. There are better ways to solve that issue. But you could for example store it in a file which you name after the has of the computers uname().